# I want Windows and OSX Apps that crashes to just close without popups / dialogs.

Tags: juce

I don't know how to google this, I tried but found nothing.

I'm doing a JUCE based Host and I need to scan plugins (VST/VST3/AU) and I wanted to make my own scanner. The current one works, but the user needs to restart the application several times, and this is not good, they hate it (and so do I).

My idea is to create a scanner app that would be shelled from the main app and check if it has crashed or not. BUT, I don't know how to check if an app has crashed. I could ping the app and see if it stops replying back, but them I don't want any crash message to show forcing the user to click something in order for my main app to continue.

I hope I'm clear, thanks for any help in advance. :-)

Best Regards, WilliamK @ Wusik

Comment: Have you considered making it so that it doesn't crash in the first place - or am I missing the point?

Comment: Txs. But that's impossible, as I will be opening 3rd party stuff that has no guarantee that it won't just crash. ;-)

Comment: What I did so far was to add an option to hide the scanner so at least it won't show up the scanner window, as it doesn't need to. I used the SW_HIDE option on Windows and now I will check what is the alternative on OSX.

Comment: Still don't know how to make my windows program not show anything when it crashes. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Found what I needed for Windows, works great.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <rtcapi.h>
int exception_handler(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS p)
{
    printf("Exception detected during the unit tests!\n");
    exit(1);
}
int runtime_check_handler(int errorType, const char *filename, int linenumber, const char *moduleName, const char *format, ...)
{
    printf("Error type %d at %s line %d in %s", errorType, filename, linenumber, moduleName);
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    DWORD dwMode = SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
    SetErrorMode(dwMode | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter((LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER)&exception_handler); 
    _RTC_SetErrorFunc(&runtime_check_handler);

    // Run your tests here

    return 0;
}
```